# Minimize Total Cost of Box

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So there is a rectangular box that has a volume of $8 m^3$. The top and bottom of the box is made with some material that has a cost of $8$ dollars per square meter. The sides are made with another material that costs $1$ dollar per square meter. How can I find the dimensions of the box that would minimize the total cost?

My thoughts:

I first started off with the equation, $V=lwh$. I think that we need to find an equation for cost in which we substitute $h$ into and then solve for two variables, then use the first derivative. I can get the concept but can't get how to work on the mechanics.

Comment: Can you write out a formula for the surface area?  Then modify it to take the differing costs into account?

Comment: @ana: Consider that the box has 6 faces and there are 3 pairs of equal sides.

Comment: @Gary Can you show what you mean?

Comment: For the cost equation, consider what you are given: material is based on area. The top and bottom of the box are $lw$ square metres each, so the total cost for those is $16lw$. Then two sides are $lh$ square metres each, and the other two are $wh$ square metres each. Consider how to find total cost from this.

Comment: @aña: Assume you tear your box carefully, and open it up : notice the north ace and south face are equal to each other, and same goes for the left- and right - faces, and the two other faces.

Comment: Hint: Lagrange Multipliers.

Comment: @aña For calculations: Are you familiar with the $\texttt{Lagrange multipliers method}$ ?

Comment: @calculus I have heard of it, but I'm not that familiar. Can you perhaps show me?

Comment: @aña You do not necessarily need the Lagrange multiplier method. You also can solve $abc=8$ for a and insert the term for a in the objective function. Then calculate the two  derivatives w.r.t b,c and set the derivatives equal to zero. Then solve b and c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Let $a$ and $b$ denote the horizontal sides of the rectangular box and $c$ its height. One seeks to solve the following problem:
\begin{align*}
\min_{(a,b,c)\in\mathbb R_+^3}&\left\{8(2ab)+1(2ac+2bc)\right\}\\\text{s.t.}\quad&\,abc=8.
\end{align*}
Substitute for $c$ using the constraint $c=8/(ab)$ and plug it into the minimand to get, after some rearrangement: $$16 ab+\frac{16}{b}+\frac{16}{a}.$$ I leave it to you to check that this function is minimized at $a=b=1$ (note that it is now an unconstrained minimization problem). Hence, the optimal solution is $$(a^{\star},b^{\star},c^{\star})=(1,1,8).$$

Comment: So how do I find the dimensions?

Comment: The way it was set up, $a$ and $b$ are the length and width with $c$ being the height.

Comment: @aña I added a figure.

Comment: What does s.t. mean?

Comment: @aña “Subject to” or “such that.” It's a standard abbreviation in constrained optimization problems.

Comment: So how do I see if it's minimized?

Comment: @aña A necessary condition is that
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\left(16 ab+\frac{16}{b}+\frac{16}{a}\right)=&\,0,\\\frac{\partial}{\partial b}\left(16 ab+\frac{16}{b}+\frac{16}{a}\right)=&\,0.
\end{align*}
Sufficiency is trickier, as the function $(a,b)\mapsto 16ab+16/b+16/a$ is not convex on the positive orthant of the plane. Honestly, I didn't check sufficiency rigorously, but I just graphed the function. Based on the graph, it is apparent that it is minimized at a unique point.

Comment: Is there another way to show

Comment: @aña I tried coming up with a two-step optimization algorithm involving only univariate calculus, but I'm afraid it's no less complicated than the one I had already posted.

Answer (score 0):

Given a box of dimensions $l,w,h$ respectively, the surface area of the box is the sum of the surface areas of the top and bottom, given by $lw+lw =2lw$ plus the surface areas of the other 4 faces: $2lh+2wh$ , for a total of $$2lw+2lh+2wh$$. This means that the total cost of he material is $8$(# of meters in top and bottom)+ 1(material on the sides)=$$8(2lw)+1(lh+wh)= 16lw+lh+wh$$ But we must do this while satisfying the condition $lhw=8$ You can do this by Lagrange multipliers, as others pointed out, or you can substitute $lhw=8$ into the original problem and turn the problem into a problem of 2 variables, which I will do here, since others have done examples with Lagrange multipliers: $$16lw+lh+wh $$ becomes then $$ f(h,w)=\frac {128}{h}+\frac{8}{w}+hw= \frac{128w+ 8h +h^2w^2}{hw}$$

Now you have a function of 2 variables and you can use the techniques to find its maxmum and minimum values:

We start considering the partials $f_h, f_w$ and we set them equalto $0$, to find the critical points and we consider the discriminant $D$, with $$D=f_{xx}f_{yy}- f^2_{xy} $$.

And we consider the possibilities:

1)$D>0, f_{xx} <0$
2)$D>0, f_{xx}>0 $

(There are other possibilities, but let's just consider these for now ).

In the case of $1$ we get a relative maximum, in the case of $2$ we get a relative minimum.

Can you see how to do it?

EDIT: The critical points are $y= 8/x^2 , x= 128/y^2$ , so that

Comment: Still unsure can you continue on

Comment: @aña: Are you stuck or confused in a specific part? All you need to do is to compute the partial derivatives $f_h, f_w, f_{hh}, f_{ww}, f_{hw}$ and then apply the ideas in the post.

Comment: What are the critical numbers

Comment: @aña: The critical values are those are the points where $f_h$ and $f_w$ are zero (simultaneously).

Comment: I know but I'm having trouble fnding them

Comment: Let me compute them.

Comment: @ana: I computed the critical values: they are : $y=8/x^2, x=128/y^2$.